# How to display an image using image_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add my first image to my html.erb page.

I added the image to the assets image folder and then added the following to the page

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
```

and a long number is displayed instead of the image.

```
<img alt="Logo 0832b7f341b4a86866d5ebbefb333a263da300acd97a6eccbc25263b235ccdc5" src="/assets/logo-0832b7f341b4a86866d5ebbefb333a263da300acd97a6eccbc25263b235ccdc5.png">
```

and if I use the following

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "logo"), "/", class: "navbar-brand navbar-brand-img") %>
```

Only the words "logo" are displayed.

Comment: Where is your image located? It should be in /assets/images directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the explanation on [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag):

> image_tag(source, options={}) public
>
> Returns an HTML image tag for the source. The source can be a full path or a file.
>
> Options
>
> You can add HTML attributes using the options. The options supports two additional keys for convenience and conformance:
>
> - **:alt - If no alt text is given, the file name part of the source is used (capitalized and without the extension)**
> - :size - Supplied as “{Width}x{Height}” or “{Number}”, so “30x45” becomes width=“30” and height=“45”, and “50” becomes width=“50” and height=“50”. :size will be ignored if the value is not in the correct format.

The numbers you see there are added to the filenames during deployment as a caching mechanism - browsers can cache these files indefinitely since the filenames will change each time they are changed.

To precompile these files and add these numbers to the filenames use `rake assets:precompile` command.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the asset pipeline, it add md5 to the image link.

> Provided that the pipeline is enabled within your application (and not disabled in the current environment context), this file is served by Sprockets. If a file exists at public/assets/rails.png it is served by the web server.
>
> Alternatively, a request for a file with an MD5 hash such as public/assets/rails-af27b6a414e6da00003503148be9b409.png is treated the same way. How these hashes are generated is covered in the In Production section later on in this guide.

see more in [coding-links-to-assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

Comment: if you precompile your assets it should work. if you don't want it you can add `:digest => false` or add `config.assets.digest = false ` to your environment file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "logo" , class:"navbar-brand navbar-brand-img"), "/" %>
```

Hope it will help you.